# Javascript ES5: Find string in array which matches pattern

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, match

I need help finding the string that matches specific patterns in an array of strings

For example

```
var array = ['hello there heretic', "purge the alien", "FOR THE EMPEROR!!" ]
```

How would I grab **"FOR THE EMPEROR!!"** if I want to find it by the following 2 separate scenarios:

1. Grab string in array which *starts* with **"FOR"**
2. Grab string in array that *contains* **"EMPEROR"**

They need to be ES5 or below though.

Comment: Any specific reason for the ES5 requirement?

Comment: should it be case-sensitive?

Comment: show what you've tried and where you are stuck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the RegEx for checking the given string matching the requirements. Like this,

```
var regEx = /(^FOR)|(.*EMPEROR.*)/i;
var array = ['hello there heretic', "purge the alien", "FOR THE EMPEROR!!" ]

array.filter(function(str) { return regEx.test(str) }) // ["FOR THE EMPEROR!!"]
```

For case-sensitive remove **i** in regex like: `/(^FOR)|(.*EMPEROR.*)/`

```js
var regEx = /(^FOR)|(.*EMPEROR.*)/i;
var array = ['hello there heretic', "purge the alien", "FOR THE EMPEROR!!", "For the champion", "And the EMPEROR" ]

const result = array.filter(function(str) { return regEx.test(str) })
console.log({result})
```

Comment: this won't work  in ES5 because you can't use `=>` syntax for functions

Comment: Updated with the function syntax

Answer (score 1):

> If you need to support lower version of IE, use `indexOf` instead of
>   `includes`.

```js
let array = ['hello there heretic', "purge the alien", "FOR THE EMPEROR!!"];

console.log(array.filter( function(el) {
    return el.indexOf("EMPEROR") > -1 && el.split(" ")[0] == "FOR"
}))
```